# not able to install oci8

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to install OCI8 for oracle purpose. I want to connect through php. I am running below command to install it through terminal

> sudo pecl install oci8

But getting this problem

```
downloading oci8-1.4.10.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-1.4.10.tgz (169,248 bytes)
.....................................done: 169,248 bytes
10 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the php headers available to compile extensions against your installed php.

On my Debian system the `php5-dev` package includes the needed files:

```
apt-get install php5-dev
```

will make it possible to install extensions via pecl. There will be a similar package available for your machine.

Looks like you're also missing autoconf. Again the Debian package is called `autoconf`, you will find a similar package for your system.